# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium

Ошибка

> File "C:\Users\milky\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-
> packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
> raise WebDriverException(
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
> Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Код

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.sport-express.ru/hockey/khl/news/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Import**

```
from pathlib import Path
```

**Code**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
pathToChromeDriver = f'{BASE_DIR}/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(pathToChromeDriver)
```

И закинь chromedriver в корень проекта