# Не запускается Chrome web driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/alexey/Dropbox/Мой\ Mac\ \(FeelQueen’s\ iMac\)/Downloads/chromedriver ; exit;')
```

ПРописывал путь /Downloads/chromedriver, оставлял просто круглые скобки, но все равно вот эта ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env, 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/alexey/Dropbox/Мой\\ Mac\\ \\(FeelQueen’s\\ iMac\\)/Downloads/chromedriver ; exit;'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexey/Dropbox/Мой Mac (FeelQueen’s iMac)/Documents/python/automation.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/alexey/Dropbox/Мой\ Mac\ \(FeelQueen’s\ iMac\)/Downloads/chromedriver ; exit;')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver ; exit;' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Какой-то у вас очень хитрый путь к файлу. А куда-нибудь попроще путь чтобы был не пробовали положить, или нельзя?

Comment: Я установил через терминал, путь оказался такой. Скачивал архив, распаковал, указвал путь. Все равно никак

Comment: А `; exit;` там в конце зачем?

Comment: В терминале этот путь дает, пробовал без ; exit; , проблема остается

Comment: Разберитесь сначала с путём. Можно с помощью библиотеки pathlib. Что выведет pathlib.Path("ваш путь").resolve() и pathlib.Path("ваш путь").exists() ?

Comment: Расскажите как прописать это

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень странный формат пути для Mac. В этой статье описано, как получить путь до файла: https://yablyk.com/348512-kak-skopirovat-polnyj-put-k-fajlu-ili-papke-v-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

ЛИБО поместите драйвер прямо в папку со скриптом и оставьте путь к файлу пустым.

Comment: Поместил в папку, все равно треюует PATH

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248479/webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path?rq=1 В этом ответе описан ещё один возможный способ решить проблему.